# Superpowered Player for Android devices stops after 2 to 3 seconds most of time

Tags: audio, superpowered

I am working with `SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer` to play song from live URL, it is not `HSL` but it plays from URL. Now, on Android device I have an issue related to play stops without any callback after 2 to 3 seconds. Is there something I need to twick or is it a known issue?

Answer (score 0):

We heard that it happens on LG Q6 devices only. Do you test on LG Q6?

Comment: Hello @Gabor its happening on many of devices like on Motorola, LG devices

Comment: Please send us your project to investigate.